# In java, insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Tags: java, webdeploy

```
private static final Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/d11459c1c17049628f462a1492c7df36"));

private static final Credentials hostCredentials = Credentials.create("666A82FC33F8134577A7BEB1BDEAA689BB72740178727691D63032432B83E0FB");

private static final BigInteger gasLimit = BigInteger.valueOf(6721975L);
private static final BigInteger gasPrice =  BigInteger.valueOf(2000000000000L);
```

Before connecting Ropsten, ganache had been linked.

`Gaslimits` and `Gasprices` are information from ganache that was used at that time.

However, there was no error in the title when I first connected to Ropsten.

```
 public String depart_wallet(String code) {
        String walletCode = "";
        switch(code) {
            case "ct_01" : 
                    walletCode = "83E094366642F531189D56DF33AC870DB53AF8C7F7F60A7A8B20CB85BC43A59F";
                    break;
            case "ft_01" :
                    walletCode = "666A82FC33F8134577A7BEB1BDEAA689BB72740178727691D63032432B83E0FB";
                    break;
            case "ms_01" :
                    walletCode = "3F0B5C58378DE554534A5A8C630AAC075886E74A6B3229000AE78F4500E153E3";
                    break;
            case "st_01" :
                    walletCode = "3B69CC479DBAC9B02D2B7C39F7829A2E5DF850203A1766355D854DD89FCC6848";
                    break;
            case "hr_01" :
                    walletCode = "3F1E2BD4EF8941731D244359F0CDF1EF079E5EAFFD57EA6D31ADDEB55E20D426";
                    break;
            case "mf_01" :
                    walletCode = "C6FD20908CDC2326A8A5E366228C149FA7632E9C4EF035F5B7EBEE1A04158B7E";
                    break;

        }
        return walletCode;
    }

 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void budgetAdd(HttpServletRequest req, Model model) throws Exception {

        String department_code = req.getParameter("dept_code");

        String deptWallet = depart_wallet(department_code);

        Credentials dept_AccountNumber = Credentials.create(deptWallet);

        System.out.println(gasPrice);
        System.out.println(gasLimit);

        **String contractAddress2 = Materal.deploy(web3j, dept_AccountNumber, gasPrice, gasLimit).send().getContractAddress();**
    }
```

> `insufficient funds for gas * price + value`

Run `Service deploy()` I met that.

Can you explain to me if anyone knows anything about this error?

An error in the subject occurs when using the `deploy()` of the method.

[image: Of course there are enough ethers in metamask.]

Comment: Welcome to SO. I have some questions to better understand what you are trying to do. Looks like you're using Java to connect to an infura node? Did your code work with ganache? Unfortunately there are some differences between ganache and the test networks. Also I am unsure what you mean by "Run Service deploy() I met that," and it looks like you're missing a description for your link.

Comment: Sorry, I remade that this code. Can you watch it again, remade code?